# How to copy a file from remote server to local machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scp, cp

In my terminal shell, I ssh'ed into a remote server, and I `cd` to the directory I want. Now in this directory, there is a file called `table` that I want to copy to my local machine `/home/me/Desktop`. How can I do this?

I tried `scp table /home/me/Desktop` but it gave an error about no such file or directory. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: in this can a remote sever be  in a different network and local machine in different network??

Answer (score 84):

For example, your remote host is example.com and remote login name is user1:

```
scp user1@example.com:/path/to/file /path/to/store/file
```

Comment: what if I am on server?

Comment: how about
`scp /path/to/local/file user1@otherhost:/path/to/file`

Comment: @kkpoon what if I am on server, and want to copy files from server to local?

Comment: If you are on the server and want to copy the file(s) to your local machine, doesn't your local machine also have to be an ssh server?

Comment: Log out of remote server. `scp` uses `ssh` below the surface. So if you give an `scp` command on your local machine, `scp` will `ssh` onto your server to copy the file. If you normally do `ssh my-user@my-server`, now do `scp my-user@my-server:/my/path/to/my.remote.file /my/path/to/my.local.file`

Answer (score 8):

The scp operation is separate from your ssh login. You will need to issue an ssh command similar to the following one assuming jdoe is account with which you log into the remote system and that the remote system is example.com:

```
scp jdoe@example.com:/somedir/table /home/me/Desktop/.
```

The scp command issued from the system where /home/me/Desktop resides is followed by the userid for the account on the remote server. You then add a ":" followed by the directory path and file name on the remote server, e.g., /somedir/table. Then add a space and the location to which you want to copy the file. If you want the file to have the same name on the client system, you can indicate that with a period, i.e. "." at the end of the directory path; if you want a different name you could use /home/me/Desktop/newname, instead. If you were using a nonstandard port for SSH connections, you would need to specify that port with a "-P n" (capital P), where "n" is the port number. The standard port is 22 and if you aren't specifying it for the SSH connection then you won't need that.

Answer (score 6):

When you use scp you have to tell the host name and ip address from where you want to copy the file. For instance, if you are at the remote host and you want to transfer the file to your pc you may use something like this:

```
scp -P[portnumber] myfile_at_remote_host [user]@[your_ip_address]:/your/path/
```

**Example:**

scp -P22 table fake_user@111.111.111.11:/home/me/Desktop/

On the other hand, if you are at your are actually on your machine you may use something like this:

```
scp -P[portnumber] [remote_login]@[remote's_ip_address]:/remote/path/myfile_at_remote_host /your/path/
```

**Example:**

scp -P22 [fake_user]@222.222.222.222:/remote/path/table /home/me/Desktop/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use sftp, use this command `sftp -oPort=7777 user@host` where -oPort is custom port number of ssh , in case if u changed it to 7777, then u can use -oPort, else if use only port 22 then plain `sftp user@host` which asks for the password , then u can log in, and u can navigate to required location using `cd /home/user` then a simple command `get table` u can download it, If u want to download a directory/folder `get -r someDirectory` will do it. If u want the file permissions also to exist then `get -Pr someDirectory`.
For uploading on to remote change get to put in above commands.